# How to analyze the amortized running time of indexed linked list operations using potential method?

Tags: heuristics, linked-lists, succinct-data-structures

I have implemented an indexed linked list that runs (under mild assumptions) all single-element operations in $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n})$ time. The description is [here](https://coderodde.github.io/weblog/#meill) and Java implementation is [here](https://github.com/coderodde/IndexedLinkedList/blob/main/src/main/java/com/github/coderodde/util/IndexedLinkedList.java).

It’s clear to me that the running time is linear in $n$ in the worst case, but I would love to see something smarter than that.

The idea is to maintain a list of *fingers*. Each finger $f$ has two fields: (1) $f.node$ pointing to a linked list node, and (2) $f.index$ being the actual index of the node pointed by $f.node$.

Now, the finger list has size $\lceil \sqrt{n} \rceil$, and it’s sorted by finger indices. Given an element index $i$, we can access it as follows:

Apply C++ lower_bound to find the closest to $i$ finger $f$, and ”rewind” $f.node$ to point to the $i$th node. (Set $f.index \leftarrow i$ also.) This applies to the get operation and runs in logarithmic time. Assuming that the fingers are distributed more or less evenly, rewinding will run in $\mathcal{O}(n / \sqrt{n} = \sqrt{n})$ time.

For the insert/removeAt operations, both do (1) finger list lookup in logarithmic time, (2) finger node rewind in $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n})$, and (3) also update the finger indices that runs in, too, $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n})$.

Comment: Is it possible for you to give a brief description on how the operations are performed, in your post? You said that based on your analysis, the running time of an access operation is $O(\sqrt n) $. Is the O(n) running-time for the other operations such as add and delete?

Comment: @Russel Done, but I will add a little more description in a moment.

Comment: @Russel Described the insert/removeAt operations. Let me know if something is missing.

Comment: What's your question?  Do you have a question?  I don't see a question in the body of your post. What have you tried?  The potential method is described in many textbooks, and writing a general exposition of the potential method is beyond the scope of an answer here.

Comment: I still don't see a question here.  A question usually ends in "?".  You talk about "the running time", but the running time of what?  Of what operation?  There seems to be a lot left out of that blog post, as it doesn't describe any of "the single-element operations" or how they are implemented.

Comment: @D.W. Fair enough. I will revise my post, but not today. See ya!

Comment: @coderodde what operation are you referring to when you said "*It’s clear to me that the running time is linear in $n$ in the worst case...*" ?

Comment: @Russel (1) get element by index (in Java, get(int index)), (2) add an element at index (add(int index), E element)), (3) remove an arbitrary element via index (remove(int index)).

Comment: But based on your implementation, shouldn't it be $O(\sqrt n)$ since you have your $\sqrt n$ fingers as shortcut to locate any index faster than $O(n)$ steps.

Comment: @Russel True. But please note that, for example, when you keep adding new elements to the tail of the list, behind the scene, the finger list becomes more sparse towards the end of the finger list.

Comment: @Russel So if we add one millioin elements, the distance between consecutive finger indices will approach $O(n)$ for the righmost fingers.

Comment: In this case, maybe you can reconstruct the fingers to balance the distribution. And maybe this will lead to a  more interesting analysis

Comment: @Russel Reconstructing fingers runs indeed in $\Theta(n)$ time, but after that analysis becomes trivial. What I am interested in is what performance guarantees one may expect if we don’t call that optimization routine.

Comment: Yes it will be $O(n)$ but I think it's possible to charge this expensive operation on some previous insert/remove to obtain an $O(\sqrt n) $ amortized running-time. What do you mean by the optimization routine? I don't seem to see it from your post.

Comment: @Russel optimization routine arranges all the fingers to point ”evenly”. (The distance between adjacent fingers is constant.)

Comment: Maybe you can add that detail in your post if that's what your really after. Because currently, like the others, I don't see the main question you are asking.

Comment: I find this discussion unfruitful to say the least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we are appending elements to the tail of the list. Suppose also that the rightmost finger has index $f$. Now, the distance between $f$ and the second rightmost finger $f - 1$ (which should be the largest since we are comparing two rightmost fingers (the distance between adjacent fingers grows as we scan the fingers from left to right)), is given by
$$
\begin{aligned}
f^2 - (f-1)^2 &= f^2 - (f^2 - 2f + 1) \\
              &= 2f - 1 \\
              &\overset{1}{=} 2\Big\lceil \sqrt{n} \Big\rceil -1\\
              &= \Theta(\sqrt{n}).
\end{aligned}
$$
We conclude that appending all the elements one by one keeps the finger indices (in asymptotic sense) evenly distributed.

(Above, we have (1) by the data structure invariant.)